# Hashcat doesn't detect any device

Tags: kali-linux, nvidia, gpu

I tried to install Nvidia drivers in Kali Linux through this tutorial:

> https://medium.com/@jamesmacwhite/installing-the-nvidia-drivers-in-kali-linux-cd3560258e24

and now everything is fine and GPU is in use, but `Hashcat` doesn't detect any device. I Googled and found some solutions like installing `nvidia-cuda-toolkit` or `clinfo`, but I already installed these.

Is there any solution to this problem?